# Python map each integer within input to int

Tags: python

If I am given an input of 1 2 3 4 5, what is the standard method of splitting such input and maybe add 1 to each integer?

I'm thinking something along the lines of splitting the input list and map each to an integer.

Comment: What do you want the result as ? List?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use list comprehension.

```
s = "1 2 3 4 5"
print [int(i)+1 for i in s.split()]
```